# Html elements drop when browser screen become smaller

Tags: html, css

```css
 <style type="text/css">
        * {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
       #Header {width:100%;height: 100px;background-color: black;}
       #Header #Tools { width: 600px;height: 100px;line-height: 100px;float: left;background-color: brown;overflow:hidden}
       #Header #Tools a {position:relative; text-align:center;padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px;border-style:solid;border-width: 5px;border-color: chartreuse;text-decoration: none;font-size: 20px;color: aliceblue;}
       #Header #Tools li { float: left;list-style: none;}
       #Header #Login {width: 150px;height: 100px; background-color: brown;float: right;line-height: 100px}
       #Header #Search {width: 700px; height: 100px;float: left;line-height: 100px; padding-left: 200px;position:relative}
       #Header #Search #Text {border:0px;height: 38px;width: 300px;padding-left: 10px; font-size: 15px;position:absolute;top:31px}
       #Header #Search #Submit {border-style: none;background: url("../pictures/search.jpg");width: 35px;height: 38px;position:absolute;top:31px;left:500px}
       #Header #Login a {border-color: chartreuse;text-decoration: none;font-size: 20px;color: aliceblue;padding-left: 10px}
       #Header #Tools .tools1_content {display:none;border-width:2px;border-style: solid;border-color:red; width: 400px;height: 250px;background-color: burlywood;position:absolute;top:80px;left:50px}

    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestPage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Header">
        <div id="Tools">
            <ul>
                <li id="Li" onmouseover="showdiv()" onmouseout="hidediv()">
                    <a href="#">Tools1</a>
                    <div class="tools1_content" id="Li_div">
                        <div>SubTools1</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Tools12</a>
                    <div class="tools1_content">
                        <div>SubTools2</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Tools13</a>
                    <div class="tools1_content">
                        <div>SubTools3</div>
                    </div>
                <li/>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="Search">
            <form>
                <input id="Text" type="text" placeholder="please enter keywords to search" />
                <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="Login">
            <a href="#">Loagin</a>
            <a href="#">Info</a>
        </div>

        <div id="Content_Left">
            <ul>
                <li>T1</li>
                <li>T2</li>
                <li>T3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[The Normal behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwMfE.png)

[The issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf3wx.png)

I just want them in one horizontal line,but when I drag the browser edge resulting in browser screen smaller.

The html element will drop to unexpected position.I want them only change in header div.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Paulie_D. You are my friends. :) :)

Comment: Look into the `@media` tag in CSS. It lets you specify what you want the page to look like at specific break points. Also, having your elements at fixed widths won't allow them to shrink when you shrink the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use float for layout unless you need support for Internet Explorer. Since flex does not work in IE<10 at all and is buggy in IE>=10.

Flexbox is widely (display: flex) used nowdays and you should rely on this.

You will need to remove or adjust the widths of the element to % values to keep everything responsive.
I set flex as display to the parent element already to keep the element horizontally aligned. (see below)

Also you should try to avoid absolute display as much as possible and also try to use % or "em" values where possible. They are more responsive and more dynamic than static px values.

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex
Responsive Design (adjust design on different sizes): https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web_Development/Mobile/Responsive_design

```css
<style type="text/css">
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#Header {
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

#Header #Tools {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: brown;
  overflow:hidden
}

#Header #Tools li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px
}

#Header #Tools a {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:50px;
  padding-right:50px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: chartreuse;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: aliceblue;
}



#Header #Login {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: brown;
  line-height: 100px
}
       
#Header #Search {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  position:relative
}

#Header #Search #Text {
  border:0px;
  height: 38px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  position:relative;
}

#Header #Search #Submit {
  border-style: none;
  background: url("../pictures/search.jpg");
  width: 35px;
  height: 38px;
  position:relative;
}

#Header #Login {
  width: 10%;
  border-color: chartreuse;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding-left: 10px
}

#Header #Login a {
  border-color: chartreuse;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding-left: 10px
}

#Header #Tools .tools1_content {
  display:none;
  border-width:2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:red;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
  left:50px
}

#Content_Left{
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestPage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Header">
            <ul id="Tools">
                <li id="Li" onmouseover="showdiv()" onmouseout="hidediv()">
                    <a href="#">Tools1</a>
                    <div class="tools1_content" id="Li_div">
                        <div>SubTools1</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Tools12</a>
                    <div class="tools1_content">
                        <div>SubTools2</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Tools13</a>
                    <div class="tools1_content">
                        <div>SubTools3</div>
                    </div>
                <li/>
           </ul>
        <div id="Search">
            <form>
                <input id="Text" type="text" placeholder="please enter keywords to search" />
                <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="Login">
            <a href="#">Loagin</a>
            <a href="#">Info</a>
        </div>
        <div id="Content_Left">
            <ul>
                <li>T1</li>
                <li>T2</li>
                <li>T3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean to say, don't use float for layout, but flex does not work in IE<10 at all and is buggy in IE>=10.

Comment: @Rob yes, i wanted to type IE 9, but after checking again it's support starts at IE 11. You're right. Let's say: do not use flex if you rely on IE support. Will edit it.

Comment: Is there other way handle this if I just want to keep float? :)

Comment: Yes! If you want to keep float (and also the fixed pixel values) then you need to use to adjust these pixel values to smaller ones to remain in the maximum width of the browser window. To set different pixel widths for different resolutions have a look at media queries => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries